# Why does my code for counting the knots of a tree work?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

I'm facing the classic "It works, but I don't know why!"-problem. I just applied a principle that I knew from another excercise with integers, but here I have to work with trees. The testing of the method was successfull. I am supposed to count the knots of a tree, and I do this bis traversing through it (in this case: inorder), and every time I traverse successfully (meaning: not facing an empty sub-tree), I count that as a knot. In this case, I'm wondering why this code doesn't count too much knots. For example, when I always go left and face an empty sub-tree, wouldn't I go up until I reach a knot where I can go right? Why does my code avoid this kind of problem?

```
public static int numberKnots (Tree b) {

  int count = 0;

  if (b.empty()) {
    return 0;
  }

  else {

  traverse.inorder(b.left());
  traverse.inorder(b.right());
  count = 1;
  }

  return count + numberKnots(b.left()) + numberKnots(b.right());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really travel up and down the tree, you only travel down and visit each node once, and you do this by making your trees More and more simple.

Consider The following tree

```
  a
 / \
b   c
   / \
  d   e
```

So you start from the root and check if it is empty which it is not, so you return the result of 1 + numberKnots(left) + numberKnots(right). left and right are also trees and they are simpler than a

```
left  right
  b    c
      / \
     d   e
```

So now you check the b tree, which is empty so it just returns 0. Then you check the c tree, which is not empty so you return 1 + countKnots(left (of c)) + countKnots(right (of c)) and so on.

Each step of the calculation would be:

```
countKnots(a) 
 = 1 + countKnots(b) + countKnots(c) 
 = 1 + 0 + countKnots(c) 
 = 1 + 0 + 1 + countKnots(d) + countKnots(e) 
 = 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + countKnots(e) 
 = 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0
 = 2
```

Your code could be simplified to

```
public static int numberKnots (Tree b) {
  if (b.empty()) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1 + numberKnots(b.left()) + numberKnots(b.right());
  }
}
```

However, it does not seem to handle tree nodes which does not contain both left and right nodes, so the following tree would cause an error

```
a
 \
  c
```

Comment: Why do you count `b` as empty? In my opinion, this is a knot too, therefore, it should give out 1, not 0.

Comment: For me, a knot is just an entry of the tree. You're tree from above shoud give out 5.

Comment: @Julian From the code in the question you do not count the node if it is "empty", and otherwise you check both left and right, so I though a node was empty if it had no left or right. I do not think that changes the overall of how traversing the tree works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using recursion,it does not transverse the same node twice.So your code works perfectly fine.consider (A) has two child nodes (B)&(C) further (B) has two childs (B1)&(B2).when transversing through recursion,it usses stack."(consider s to be our stack)". First the control reaches node(A) and since it has left child (A) is pushed into stack and control is trasferred to (B) now control is trasferred to (B)'s left child(B1) and (B) is pushed into stack, since (B1) does not have any childs it is counted and control is trasferred to top of stack i.e (B) and (B) is counted now control is trasffered to (B)'s right child it (B2)and (B2) is counted and control is trasferred to (B).Now (B) does not have any part of code left thus it is popped from stack and control is trasfered to (A) and (A) is counted and control is transfered to its right child (c).Similarly all nodes are counted without duplicating.

Hope it helps